# How to add labels in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

```
x2016 = data[data.year == 2016].iloc[:20,:]
num_students_size  = [float(each.replace(',', '.')) for each in x2016.num_students]
international_color = [float(each) for each in x2016.international]
trace1 = go.Scatter(
x = x2016.world_rank,
y = x2016.teaching,
mode = "markers",
marker=dict(
color = international_color,
size = num_students_size,
showscale = True
),
text = x2016.university_name
)
data5 = [trace1]
iplot(data5)
```

This gives bubble plot and it does not show labels . How to add labels please help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9d79.png)

Comment: What is "go"? Did you try passing the dataframe and then x,y,text as column names as in `scatter(x2016, x="world_rank", y="teachings", text="university_name"...)`?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display a text label next to the data points, where the label comes from `text=x2016.university_name`? If that's the case you should set `mode="markers+text"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `[data5]` would be better suited as a `go.Figure()` object.

There is a good sequence here to follow: https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#bubble-scatter-plots

Here is the reference to figure labels:
https://plotly.com/python/figure-labels/

```
fig.update_layout(
    title="Plot Title",
    xaxis_title="x Axis Title",
    yaxis_title="y Axis Title",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=18,
        color="#7f7f7f"
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Additional relevant help and tutorials here:
https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/

So - to give a generic hint here, something like the following should work:

```
data5 = go.Figure(data=trace1,
    title="Plot Title",
    xaxis_title="x Axis Title",
    yaxis_title="y Axis Title"
)
iplot(data5)
```